# How to wait for multiple useLazyQuery in react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a `gql` query `MY_Q`
and have a list of the data items, like `data_list = [data1, data2]`

how to group multiple `useLazyQuery()` on each data item and wait until all the query has finished before processing the data.

similar to `Promise.all()`.

example:-

```
Promise.all (data_list.map((e) => useLazyQuery(MY_Q , { variables : { data : 
e}}))).then ((res) {
 //process result.
})
```

Comment: use `client.query`, not hooks ... https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapollo%5D+client.query

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use promises because you will want what the hooks returns in your React component won't you?

Just define the hook for each separate query and then render based on what is returned so far.  When everything is fetched render that, if not, render a loading view in the component.

```
function SomeComponent () {
  const [fetchInitial, {data, fetchMore}] = useLazyQuery(QUERY, {
    variables: {
      dataSets: [
        dataSet1,
        dataSet2
      ]
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: ya, but the data_list is dynamic, and if i create multiple query and store it in a list and call all of them in a forEach(), React complaints that the query cannot be called in call back function

Comment: Dynamic?  You mean you don't know how many queries will need to be executed?  Seems a little odd.  Sounds like a problem with the schema then.  What's the general context?  If it is the same query that is being performed but with different variables surely all these variables ought to be in the same variables set?  For example if i want pages 1 to 10 i would send this over in one go; not repeat the query ten times.

Comment: that would be last option, but it should be possible to query without renderings the components if we don't want to. as we can set state manually to trigger the render

Comment: Rendering the component here multiple times shouldn't be your concern.  After all you show in the UI what you want based on the state of the component.  Hitting the network multiple times should be a greater concern.  Based on what you've said you should be doing this in a single query.

Comment: so, is there any possible way to group the above, queries, since if i have another list and have to again register the new query to backend, or this is limitation for react with gql.

Comment: It sounds like you need to redesign the schema.  For example I have a dashboard component in an app I'm building at the moment.  It consists of sub components which contain their own lists.  Each component has its own query.  It I needed to change the number of items showing in the list for example the pageSize would be sent to the server.  I wouldn't execute one query for one lot and then repeat the query for the next lot.

Comment: but, here don't want to create multiple component, since i want all the data in one place to process further, sure with multiple component with its own query will work, but the question if can we bundle  queries with multiple variable and wait in single component.

Comment: I was just giving an example which involves multiple components.  Even with a single component though you should define this query as one and all the what you are defining as different sets of variables needs to be one group of variables.